# How is the final array constructed in this Ruby quicksort implementation?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I'm learning some soring algorithms in Ruby, and learned this recursive implementation of quicksort:

```
class Array
  def quicksort
    return [] if empty?

    pivot = delete_at(rand(size))

    left, right = partition(&pivot.method(:>))

    return *left.quicksort, pivot, *right.quicksort
  end
end

array = [5,3,2,18,1,6,4,7,5,9,0]
p array
#=> [5, 3, 2, 18, 1, 6, 4, 7, 5, 9, 0]

p array.quicksort
#=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 9, 18]
```

I think I understand basically what's happening here. Do I have this right?

Chose an arbitrary pivot, store the number and delete that index from the array. Then partition the array, putting numbers `> pivot` in an array `left`, and the numbers `< pivot` in `right`. `Return pivot` and call quicksort recursively on `left` and `right` arrays if they have anything in them.

What I don't understand is how the final array is constructed; I don't see where the returned numbers are assigned the appropriate index. Does it happen when `pivot` is returned? How does it end up in the right index?

I think some of my confusion is coming from a lack of understanding about recursion.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `return` with a list of values, Ruby turns the list into an array and returns the array.

```
def return_array
  return 1, 2
end
return_array
#=> [1, 2]
```

This can be used in conjunction with the [**Array to Arguments Conversion**](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion), which turns an array into a list of elements with the splat operator '`*`'.

```
a = [1, 2]
def add(c, d)
  c + d
end
add(*a)
#=> 3
```

The return statements in the quicksort method does this trick, it returns a list with

1. The **splat** quick sort result of the left, which are all the elements that's less than the pivot (`pivot.method(:>).call(elem)`, i.e., `pivot > elem`)
2. The pivot
3. The **splat** quick sort result of the right, which are all the elements that's greater or equal than the pivot (`! (pivot > elem)`)

And Ruby turns them into an array and return that array.

Comment: AHA! I see where I went wrong. Left gets the values that are LESS than the pivot! I had left and right reversed. It makes perfect sense now. The pivot stays where it is in the list, its correct position relative to everything else, and the left and right are sorted recursively until all numbers filter down to the right position. That sorted list is returned as the array.